# Do I have to re-check luggage on connecting flight?

Tags: luggage, frankfurt

My first flight will be from Amsterdam to Frankfurt , and then from Frankfurt to Newark . Is it necessary to reclaim my luggage or is it done for me ?

Comment: can you tell more about your flight (one ticket or two different tickets), which airline?

Comment: I booked with Lufthansa. I have a boardingpass for AMS-FRA and for FRA-EWR.

Comment: @FOPYX Right, but did you book it on a single ticket (i.e., is there only one one ticket number for both flights)? This actually makes a difference. If it is a single ticket, then you do not need to recheck your luggage. If you booked the connection as two separate tickets, you will need to recheck your luggage.

Comment: If you mean booking reference then yes they are the same for both AMS-FRA and FRA-EWR. I booked this flight as a combination on Lufthansa's site.

Comment: @FOPYX Then, your luggage will be checked through. The ticket number is, by, the way, printed on your boarding passes. There are some cases in which you can have different booking references, but the parts of your journey are still on the same ticket, hence the question whether the ticket number is the same.

Comment: There is an ETKT ( I presume E-ticket) number which is the same luckily. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Since both legs are on the same ticket, your bags will be checked through to Newark, and to Amsterdam on the way home. You can check with the check-in agent that this has been done, in both cases.

When you're travelling on one ticket, bags are almost always checked through. One semi-exception to this is that, if you were taking an internal flight in the US, you'd need to collect your bags at Newark to take them through US customs there. But even then, there's a special re-check counter and your bag is technically checked through; you wouldn't need to go to the main check-in area. This doesn't apply to you, since Newark is your final destination.